# How to Fix error while trying to get users list in Slack

Tags: postman, slack, slack-api, slack-commands

I am trying fetch the users details using PostMan i am getting below error.

```
users.list
```

Headers passing  Token & Content-Type as urlencoded

When i test i am getting:

```
"error": "not_authed"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`not_authed` means that the Slack API did not recognize your token. This is properly due to an encoding mismatch.

In Postman make sure to set your request to `https://slack.com/api/users.list` as POST.

In Body set to `x-www-form-urlencoded` and set at key for `token`.

Do not set any Auth or Headers yourself (Postman will do that for you. The Header `Content-Type` will be set to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` though)

You can also more simply fetch the user list with a GET request and just add the token as URL parameter. No encoding setting for the body required.